# Working with webpack generated Vue project

Tags: vue.js, webpack

We have a VueJS project with the WebPack-generated code. The source file is now incomplete (we have huge chunks of the original project but we can no longer generate the complete web app using source files now.)

The following is an example of a page in the generated app:

```
(window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || []).push([["pages-image-info"], {"017c": function (t, i, n) {
    "use strict";
    n.r(i);
    var a = n("03e4"), e = n.n(a);
```

The trouble is we need to make minor changes (such as replacing tags) to the generated project before we rework the original project or develop the project from scratch. I would like to get guidelines on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To make changes to a generated Vue project, especially when you don't have access to the original source files, you can follow these steps:

1. **Understand the Webpack Bundle:**

   - Webpack bundles your Vue project into one or more JavaScript files. The code you've posted is likely a part of such a bundle.
2. **Decompile and Analyze:**

   - Since you don't have the original source code, you might want to decompile the minified/obfuscated code to make it more readable. There are tools available for this, such as [source-map-explorer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer) or online tools like [sourcemap-decompiler](https://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization/).
3. **Make Changes:**

   - Once you have a better understanding of the code, you can make the necessary changes directly to the generated code. Be cautious, though, as this might be error-prone, and you might need to manually test your changes.
4. **Use a Code Formatter:**

   - After making changes, you might want to use a code formatter to ensure the code maintains proper formatting. Tools like Prettier can help.
5. **Testing:**

   - Manually test your changes to ensure that the modified code still works as expected. This may involve running the project and checking for any errors or unexpected behavior.
6. **Automate if Possible:**

   - If you find yourself needing to make these changes often, consider creating a script or using a tool to automate the process.
7. **Documentation:**

   - Document the changes you made and why. This will be crucial for anyone who works on this project in the future.
8. **Consider Upgrading:**

   - If you are making changes to an older version of a project, consider upgrading to a newer version if possible. Newer versions might have improvements and better tooling.
9. **Backup:**

   - Always make backups before making significant changes to the code. This ensures that you can revert to a working state if something goes wrong.
10. **Legal Considerations:**

    - Be aware of any licensing or legal implications when modifying generated code. Some licenses might prohibit modifying and redistributing the code.

Remember that modifying generated code is not an ideal solution, and if possible, you should try to obtain the original source code or recreate the project from scratch to have better maintainability and control. If you're dealing with a large and complex project, consider reaching out to the original developers or project maintainers for assistance.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insights. We own the project. We just don't have the complete projects. Also original developers have left. We only need to make minor changes to the project before we migrate.